# Скрыть часть изображения ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, view

Не могу догадаться как скрыть часть картинки, в разметке ConstraintLayout, не вешая поверх View,хочу сделать как на картинке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте подробнее описать что и как нужно скрыть. Это не очевидно из картинки. На картинке виден разноцветный космический корабль и какая-то дуга.

Comment: Дизайн картинки в фигма, корабль виден не полностью и его выделил что бы понимали, что какая-то часть скрыта под фоном